# SCANF FUNCTION PROBLEM IN C IN VS CODE

Tags: css, code, css-framework, vs

When i am writing a code with printf in c, the output is showing. But when i am taking a user input/inroducing the scanf function in the code ,then the output is not coming. It is showing that the program is still running.

Comment: Questions about [coding/programming](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic for this site and best asked over at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).